# How to find correct value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about finding the correct value from my scenario.
I have two table like this:

### shift table

```
shift_id | shift_user | gate
-------- | ---------- | ------
   1     |     1001   |   1
   1     |     1001   |   2
   1     |     1001   |   3
   2     |     1002   |   1
   2     |     1002   |   2
   2     |     1002   |   3
   3     |     1003   |   1
   3     |     1003   |   3
```

### Transaction Table

```
id   |  shift_id  |  sale   |   gate
-----|------------|---------|----------
  1  |     1      |  2000   |     1
  2  |     1      |  30000  |     2
  3  |     1      |  40000  |     3
  4  |     2      |  300    |     1
  5  |     2      |  4000   |     2
  6  |     2      |  3200   |     3
  7  |     3      |  5500   |     1
  8  |     3      |  100000 |     3
```

How to calculate sum of the sales for each shift_id?

Please provide me a good way with query.

Thanks a lot.

:)

EDIT

From the comment section of an answer it became clear that we need to get the sum of sales of a specific shift.

Comment: Maybe sit down with any basic beginners book or tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question.
I have used following query:

```
select sum(sale) from transaction inner join shift on shift.shift_id=transaction.shift_id and shift.gate=transaction.gate;
```

This returns the correct result.
Thank for your reply, dear friends.

Answer (score 2):

That's a simple grouping query. Try this:

```
SELECT shift_id, SUM(sale)
FROM transactions
GROUP BY shift_id;
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/690369/860551/)

Comment: I have used it, but it sums three gate, while i want the sum of one shift. for example: the value for shift_id=1 is 216000 that it isn't correct value.

Comment: @mseraj . . . This answer (as well as the other but this is better) answers your question as asked.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question.  Modifying the question will invalidate these answers, potentially drawing downvotes to people who tried to help you.

Comment: So what do you exactly want? You want the sum for each gate? If so, just add the gate to the `group by`. If that's not what you want, please clarify.

Comment: No, I don't want the value of each gate, I want total sum of one shift, but the join query return the 216000 value that it isn't correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're talking about. My answer gives you the sum for each shift. According to the data in your question, my query should give you 72000 for `shift_id=1`. How are you getting 216000? Are you using different data?

Comment: I added a fiddle to my answer. You can clearly see that the result for `shift_id=1` is 72000, not 216000 like you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

Use query like:

```
Select s.shift_id, sum(sale) from shift s INNER JOIN transaction 
ON s.shift_id=t.shift_id group by s.shift_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need simple grouping

```
select shift_id, sum(sale)
from transactions
group by shift_id
```

If you need to get this result for a specific group, then do it like this

```
select shift_id, sum(sale)
from transactions
group by shift_id
having shift_id = 1
```